# Issue in Parsing Lisp input to python

Tags: python, lisp, pyparsing

I am trying to parse lisp input to python list. But when I parse the input I get list of strings but I want individual element as int.

Example: When I parse following input: `"(2 (10 (5 11))) (5 6) (4)"`
Output: `[[['2'], ['10', '5']], [['5'], ['6']], [['4']]]`

I use: `[[map(int, x) for x in lst] for lst in test]` to convert the strings to `int` but this function will only parse nested list of level 2. But if I have a nested list of more than 2, how should I use it to parse?

I tried pyparsing but I didn't understand it properly.

Comment: Can you show the parsing code you used? The best solution will probably involve a change there rather than a post-processing step.

Comment: In pyparsing, you can attach a parse action to do the integer string-to-int conversion at parse time. Look at this example http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/chemicalFormulas.py/31041705/chemicalFormulas.py on the pyparsing wiki. See in the internal Version 2 of the parser, how the `convertIntegers` method is attached to the `integer` expression. This does the string-to-int conversion at parse time, rather than having to post-process later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use pyparsing, you could do so without any postprocessing as follows.

```
import pyparsing as pp

integer = pp.Word(pp.nums).setParseAction(lambda m:int(m[0]))
expr = pp.Forward()
expr << pp.nestedExpr(content=pp.OneOrMore(integer | expr))
manyExpr = pp.OneOrMore(expr)

print manyExpr.parseString('(2 (10 (5 11))) (5 6) (4)')
    #returns [[2, [10, [5, 11]]], [5, 6], [4]]
```

This first defines an integer as something consisting only of numbers, and tells pyparsing how to convert it from a string of numbers to an integer object.  Next, it makes defines an expression as a list of expressions or integers inside parentheses.  Finally, in order to parse your example, it looks for many consecutive expressions.

Comment: Even simpler is to recognize that `nestedExpr` internally handles repetition and nesting of the content - just define `expr` as `expr = pp.nestedExpr(content=integer)`.  (Good use of a parse action to convert the numeric strings to integers at parse time, btw. And also a nice summary description of the makeup of the overall parser.)

Answer (score 5):

```
def as_int(xs):
    if isinstance(xs, list):
        return map(as_int, xs)
    elif isinstance(xs, str):
        return int(xs)
    return xs
```

Usage:

```
>>> xs = [[['2'], ['10', '5']], [['5'], ['6']], [['4']]]
>>> print as_int(xs)
[[[2], [10, 5]], [[5], [6]], [[4]]]
```